# How does C++ compiler implement the reverse call order of destructors in inheritance?

Tags: c++

For example, we know that the following code will execute as detailed:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
  virtual ~Base() {
    std::cout << "Destroying base" << std::endl;
  }
};

class Derived: public Base {
public:
  ~Derived() {
    std::cout << "Destroying derived" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
  Base* p = new Derived();
  delete p;
}
```

```sh
$ g++ --std=c++11 main.cc -o main; ./main
Destroying derived
Destroying base
```

How is that behavior implemented by the compiler? The answer will probably need to talk about implementation of vtable as well.

A high-level, easy to understand answer is highly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean "how is it implemented"? The C++ standard defines an algorithm and the compiler simply follows it.

Comment: I don't understand what kind of answer you're looking for. There is the C++ specification, and the compiler can implement it however it wants.

Comment: re -- thanks for the reply. I am not very familiar with C++ specification, and by "implementation", I mean at the level of discussing both static inference and how the emitted code works dynamically.

Comment: you'll need to specify of which compiler you are asking about, the C++ specification just says this is the behavior that the compiler needs to have. It's then up to the compiler to implement it, every compiler can implement it however it wants so you can't really have a single answer "it is always done like this".

Comment: @JohnDoe Isn't it like vtables or two's compliment, where C++ standard doesn't specify the implementation, but every major compiler implements it in this way anyway?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen that may be but they are not forced to do so, hence you can't be certain unless you check every single compiler's code and even then it may change at any time only for one compiler (unlikely but still theoretically possible). I'm not that knowledgeable in compiler implementations, so I wouldn't know how to answer a question about a specific one, but the answer to the more general "how do compilers implement this?" is the good old "It depends".

Comment: If you're really interested in the gory details, [here is the Clang code generation for a class' destructor](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/0861889be103bf7bcf013768e913695ed94b50bf/clang/lib/CodeGen/CGClass.cpp#L1791-L1903)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the C++ perspective, constructors and destructors are special functions. They don't have return types, for instance.

The typical C++ compiler is likely to use still generate a fairly normal function, at least from its perspective. This keeps the linker simpler. But the function may contain a bit more than just your own C++ code. You can't get the address of this function, though.

In this particular case, the compiler is likely to inline a call to `Base::~Base` in the binary of `Derived::~Derived`. It's simple enough, there's no virtual or multiple inheritance complicating things.

The comments suggest that the vtable might be involved. Obviously, for compilers that use vtables, they'll need to put an entry for `Derived::~Derived` in that table since it's `virtual`. That will likely be the same regular function which contains the inlined `Base::~Base` call.